# Removendo caractéres de uma string - Python

Tags: python, string

Galera, estou com o seguinte problema.

Tenho uma função que me retorna o seguinte output:

```
"Address:58.200.133.200"
```

Gostaria de salvar esse valor em uma variável `ip`, porém eu quero apenas a parte do ip desde output, para que fique `ip = "58.200.133.200"`.

Eu não tenho acesso a função que gera esse output, apenas chamo ela atráves de uma API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se sua string tem sempre esse formato, pegue simplesmente seu sufixo - pois o prefixo `Address:` (8 letras) é fixo:

```
s = "Address:58.200.133.200"
ip = s[8:]
```

Caso sua entrada possua alguma variância, o uso de expressões regulares pode ser mais interessante, [como apontado na resposta do Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33926/215).

Answer (score 1):

Acho que seria o caso de usar uma [expressão regular](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html):

```
import re
p = re.compile("Address:([\d\.]*)")
match = p.match(sua_string)
resultado = match.group()
```

Answer (score 1):

Se não usar regex como o colega explicou, pode fazer:

```
>>> txt = "Address:58.200.133.200"
>>> txt.split(':')
['Address', '58.200.133.200']
>>> txt.split(':')[0]
'Address'
>>> txt.split(':')[1]
'58.200.133.200'
```